# Make a single property optional in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, 2.2...

Let's say I have a Person type:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}
```

And I'd like to create a function that returns a Person, but doesn't require a nickname:

```
function makePerson(input: ???): Person {
  return {...input, nickname: input.nickname || input.name};
}
```

What should be the type of `input`? I'm looking for a dynamic way to specify a type that is identical to `Person` except that `nickname` is optional (`nickname?: string | undefined`). The closest thing I've figured out so far is this:

```
type MakePersonInput = Partial<Person> & {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
}
```

but that's not quite what I'm looking for, since I have to specify all the types that are *required* instead of the ones that are optional.

Comment: be aware, most of the answers (if not all till this date), loses information on the union type, as in this `type Description = { id: string } & ({
    type: "hooman";
    iq: number
} | {
    type: "meow";
    fur: "average" | "less"
});
let a: Omit<Description, "id"> = {
    type: "hooman",
    iq: -200,
};`

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You can also do something like this, partial only some of the keys.

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type PartialBy<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>

interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}

type MakePersonInput = PartialBy<Person, 'nickname'>
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Note you can pass more than one property:

type OnlyNameIsMandatory = PartialBy<Person, 'nickname'|'hometown'>

Comment: A quick note, the `Omit` helper type is now available by default in [TypeScript 3.5+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the-omit-helper-type). So if you are using TS 3.5 or above you no longer need to define `Omit` yourself.

Comment: what if  I also want to add some extra properties to MakePersonInput?

Comment: @ThanosM you can use 
`interface PersonExtended extends MakePersonInput { some_prop: string; }`
or intersection type
`type MakePersonInput = PartialBy<Person, 'nickname'> & {some_prop: string}`

Comment: `Pick<T,K>` actually doesn't seem to be necessary: `Omit<T, K> & Partial<T>` gets the job done as well.

Comment: Hi,  how  about nested atrribute  something like 
If there an attribute object that need to be partial , how can i do it ?

For exemple, I want address to be partial


`  
interface Person {
      name: string;
      hometown: string;
      nickname: string;
      address: Address
    }

     interface Address {
            street: string,
            city: string
     }
`

Comment: This works, but now VSCode shows me the "unjoined" type `Omit<..> & Partial<...>` as an editor hint, which is incredably hard to look at. Any way to mitigate this?

Answer (score 196):

Here is my Typescript 3.5+ Optional utility type

```
type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<Partial<T>, K> & Omit<T, K>;

// and your use case
type MakePersonInput = Optional<Person, 'nickname'>

// and if you wanted to make the hometown optional as well
type MakePersonInput = Optional<Person, 'hometown' | 'nickname'>
```

Comment: This is beautyful!

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind to explain the logic behind it?

Comment: Sure! `Optional` takes two arguments, `T` is the type we want to base our optional type, and `K` represents a set of keys that are available on the type `T`.

`Partial<T>` returns a type with all of the keys in `T` marked as optional. 
Surrounding the `Partial<T>` with a `Pick<...,K>` gives us a type with only the keys that we supplied, which we have already made optional.
Using `Omit<T,K>` gives us a type without any of the keys that we have specified.
By using an `&`, it will union the two types together.

Comment: Mulling it over more, there might be a shorter way of accomplishing the same thing - but feels cleaner in my mind building two types with no overlapping keys and merging them together.

Comment: in that case there is:
`type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Pick<Partial<T>, K>`

Comment: `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` is the underlying source of `Omit<T, K>` in `lib.es5.d.ts`.

Comment: I wanted the opposite of this...make all properties optional except for the ones I specify. This is what I came up with:

`type MostlyOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<T> & Pick<T, K>;`

I'd share a link to the TS Playground demo'ing this but the URLs are too dang long!

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. But it seems that it also works without the `Pick`. i.e. `Partial<T> & Omit<T, K>` works the same. Not sure if I missed something.

Comment: Hi Kevin - as I mentioned above, it "feels cleaner in my mind building two types with no overlapping keys and merging them together". Relying on the intersection logic to override some keys feels dirtier to me (and functionally, is possibly undocumented and open to change in the future - I cannot quickly find documentation regarding precedence of intersected overlapping keys)

Answer (score 42):

For a plug and play solution, consider using the brilliant [`utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) package:

```sh
npm i utility-types --save
```

Then simply make use of [`Optional<T, K>`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#optionalt-k):

```
import { Optional } from 'utility-types';

type Person = {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}

type PersonWithOptionalNickname = Optional<Person, 'nickname'>;

// Expect:
//
// type PersonWithOptionalNickname {
//   name: string;
//   hometown: string;
//   nickname?: string;
// }
```

Answer (score 21):

**Update:**

As of TypeScript 2.8, this is supported much more concisely by *Conditional Types*! So far, this also seems to be more reliable than previous implementations.

```
type Overwrite<T1, T2> = {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T1, keyof T2>]: T1[P]
} & T2;

interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}

type MakePersonInput = Overwrite<Person, {
  nickname?: string;
}>

function makePerson(input: MakePersonInput): Person {
  return {...input, nickname: input.nickname || input.name};
}
```

As before, `MakePersonInput` is equivalent to:

```
type MakePersonInput = {
    name: string;
    hometown: string;
} & {
    nickname?: string;
}
```

**Outdated:**

As of TypeScript 2.4.1, it looks like there's another option available, as proposed by GitHub user ahejlsberg in a thread on type subtraction: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type Overwrite<T, U> = { [P in Diff<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[P] } & U;

interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}
type MakePersonInput = Overwrite<Person, {
  nickname?: string
}>
function makePerson(input: MakePersonInput): Person {
  return {...input, nickname: input.nickname || input.name};
}
```

According to Intellisense, `MakePersonInput` is equivalent to:

```
type MakePersonInput = {
    name: string;
    hometown: string;
} & {
    nickname?: string;
}
```

which looks a little funny but absolutely gets the job done.

On the downside, I'm gonna need to stare at that `Diff` type for a while before I start to understand how it works.

Comment: Note that this makes any optional fields in the original interface required

Comment: use this to keep optional fields - type Overwrite<T1, T2> = Pick<T1, Exclude<keyof T1, keyof T2>> & T2;

Answer (score 13):

The [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest#utilities) package has a utility `SetOptional` - https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/set-optional.d.ts

```js
import { SetOptional } from 'type-fest';

type PersonWithNicknameOptional = SetOptional<Person, 'nickname'>
```

I find the library is well-maintained, and supports latest versions of typescript.  It's worth adding in a typescript project IMO.

Answer (score 11):

If you use a recent version of typescript, a simple solution is to do

```js
function makePerson(input: Omit<Person, 'nickname'> & { nickname?: string }): Person {
  return {...input, nickname: input.nickname || input.name};
}
```

Basically you remove the "nickname" property from the interface and re-add it as optional

If you want to make sure to keep it in sync with the original interface you can do

```js
Omit<Person, 'nickname'> & Partial<Pick<Person, 'nickname'>>
```

which will warn you if you ever change the "nickname" prop in the original interface

Answer (score 0):

Ok well what you are really describing is two different "Types" of people (i.e. Person types) .. A normal person and a nick named person.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    hometown: string;
}

interface NicknamedPerson extends Person {
    nickname: string;
}
```

Then in the case where you don't really want a nicknamed person but just a person you just implement the Person interface.

An alternative way to do this if you wanted to hang on to just one Person interface is having a different implementation for a non nicknamed person:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname: string;
}
class NicknamedPerson implements Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public hometown: string, public nickname: string) {}
}

class RegularPerson implements Person {
    nickname: string;
    constructor(public name: string, public hometown: string) {
        this.nickname = name;
    }
}

makePerson(input): Person {
     if(input.nickname != null) {
       return new NicknamedPerson(input.name, input.hometown, input.nickname);
     } else {
       return new RegularPerson(input.name, input.hometown);
     }
}
```

This enables you to still assign a nickname (which is just the persons name in case of an absence of a nickname) and still uphold the Person interface's contract.  It really has more to do with how you intend on using the interface.  Does the code care about the person having a nickname?  If not, then the first proposal is probably better.

Comment: Hi... so... this is a great response to the question I asked, but not so much for what I'm actually trying to solve :/ Sorry for the oversimplification of the question. In the terms of what I asked... basically, every Person _must_ have a nickname, but I don't want this function to require it. If it's not provided, it'll just use the `name` input.

Comment: I edited my answer to better illustrate the second option I was advocating.  Let me know if we still aren't on the same page?  Notice that the RegularPerson constructor makes the "nickname" value equal to the "name" value of input.

Comment: `input` here is still missing a type, which is the tricky part of this question... I think what I'm trying to do just isn't possible in TypeScript yet. I think I'm going to self-answer with what I found.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I think what I'm trying to do just isn't possible in TypeScript... *yet*. When [spread/rest types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) land, I think it will be, though, with syntax something along the lines of `{ ...Person, nickname?: string }`.

For now, I've gone with a more verbose approach, declaring the properties that *are* required:

```
type MakePersonInput = Partial<Person> & {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
};
function makePerson(input: MakePersonInput): Person {
  return {...input, nickname: input.nickname || input.name};
}
```

This unfortunately requires me to update `MakePersonInput` whenever I add more required properties to `Person`, but it's impossible to forget to do this, because it will cause a type error in `makePerson`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export type Optional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] | undefined; }
```

If you want to cover the case when the key is not passed at all, or it is passed but with value set to `undefined`

Answer (score -2):

I reformatted your code to this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  hometown: string;
  nickname?: string;
}
```

TypeScript 5.
The question mark "?" denotes an optional property or method in an interface or class.

In the code I provided, the "nickname" property is marked with a question mark, which means that it's optional. It indicates that instances of the Person interface may or may not have a nickname property.

If a Person object has a nickname property, it must be a string type. However, if it doesn't have a nickname property, it won't cause a compilation error. This makes it possible to define objects that conform to the Person interface with or without a nickname property.

Comment: that does not help to answer the question asked. Noone wants to rewrite manually the type definition with optional property, the question was about how to transfer a type to another type in a functional manner.