# How to make some fields in object required

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need an interface for making some fields of other interface as required. 
For example: I have IUserInterface:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  role?: string;
}

interface IUserFromDB {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  role: string;
}
```

When I create new user - role is optional. DB set default role and when I select user from DB - `role` must be in `userObject`. 
I can write Interfaces like I've written above, but in a real project  this approach creates a lot of redundant code. So, I need some interface, that help me to get old interface and make some optional fields as required.

I want something like this:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  role?: string;
}

type IUserFromDB = WithRequired<IUser, 'role'[|...]> & {
  id: number;
  ...;
};
```

Please help me to create this `WithRequired` type.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a single property optional in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159887/make-a-single-property-optional-in-typescript)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Keeping your IUser interface

Using [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt), [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk), and [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt):

```js
interface IUser {
    name: string;
    role?: string;
}

type IUserFromDB = Partial<IUser> & Required<Pick<IUser, 'name' | 'role'>> & {
    id: number;
    ...;
};
```

In this case the use of `Partial` is not required unless `IUser` grows. As it does not affect in run time, I suggest to keep it anyway :)

## Alternative approach

With a common fully-required model and using [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) and [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) for any derived type:

```js
interface IUserModel {
    name: string;
    role: string;
}

type IUser = Partial<IUserModel> & Pick<IUserModel, 'name'>; 

type IUserFromDB = Partial<IUserModel> & Pick<IUserModel, 'name' | 'role'> & {
    id: number;
    ...;
};
```

Answer (score 23):

You can create a helper type and use it like this:

```js
// Helper type
export type RequiredFields<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>;


// Use
RequiredFields<IUser, 'role'>
```

For multiple fields you can use a union type:

```js
RequiredFields<IUser, 'role' | 'someField'>
```

Comment: You can use it also for multiple fields with `RequiredField<IUser, 'role' | 'someField'>`, so I think more appropriate name for that type would be `RequiredFields` (plural)