# Make some attributes required in an imported type

Tags: typescript

I am importing a type which for some reason is entirely consisted of optional types. So something like this (but instead with over a dozen attributes):

```
type MyType {
  id?: string
  name?: string
  age?: number
  description?: string
}
```

This is causing some issues as I do need for some of these to be required. I know there is the [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type  which turns all attributes into required.

The issue is, then I have the opposite problem in which indeed some of the types are intended to be optional.

What I would like to do is to change `MyType` in such a way that I can pick which attributes should be mandatory and which should be optional. Ideally I would like it to look something like this:

```
type MyType {
  id: string // required
  name: string // required
  age?: number // optional
  description?: string // optional
}
```

Is there a util type or something else I can do to cherry-pick which ones I'd like to make mandatory and which ones should remain optional?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make some fields in object required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528740/how-to-make-some-fields-in-object-required)