# TypeScript: Restrict an existing interface by restricting certain properties with constraints

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript interface that is used as a database entity for an ORM library:

```
export interface Entity {
  id?: number;
  someColumn: string;
  someOtherValue: number;
  otherColumn: string;
}
```

Notice the optional `id` property, which is either the primary key of the entity or undefined.
If it is undefined, then this means that the entity does not exist in the underlying database.

However, many functions only accept `Entity`-objects that have a valid id.
Therefore, I would like to introduce a new interface that looks like this (without the "?"):

```
export interface ValidEntity {
  id: number;
  someColumn: string;
  someOtherValue: number;
  otherColumn: string;
}
```

Now my problem is that I do not want to duplicate all the properties from the original `Entity`-interface.
How can I "extend" the `Entity`-interface with a constraint to enforce that `id` must not be undefined?

## Reversing The Question

Another question is the same thing in the opposite direction.
Suppose that we already have the `ValidEntity` interface and want to create an `Entity` interface that relaxes the `id` property to allow undefined. How can we accomplish this relaxation without duplicating properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there might be other ways that produce prettier error messages,
a quick intersection type will do the trick.

```js
export interface Entity {
  id?: number;
  someColumn: string;
  someOtherValue: number;
  otherColumn: string;
}

type ValidEntity = Entity & { id: number };
// Alternate solution:
// type RequiredBy<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>>
// type ValidEntity = RequiredBy<Entity, "id">

function f(e: ValidEntity) { }

let obj = {
    someColumn: "1",
    someOtherValue: 2,
    otherColumn: "3"
}

f(obj);
// Property 'id' is missing in type '{ someColumn: string; someOtherValue: 
// number; otherColumn: string; }' but required in type '{ id: number; } '.
```

Going the opposite direction is a little bit more tricky. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178819/7619380), you can use utility types as follows:

```js
type PartialBy<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>

interface ValidEntity {
  id: number;
  someColumn: string;
  someOtherValue: number;
  otherColumn: string;
}

type Entity = PartialBy<ValidEntity, 'id'>
```

Comment: Works great, can you also give a hint on how to do this in the opposite direction? (I updated the original question)

Comment: A "union type" might do it in the opposite direction, but it is not quite the thing that is necessary.

Comment: Edited to add answer.